# Javascript object losing attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of a problem with this function:

```
function create_enemies(rows, columns) {
    var i, j;

    var x_position = 0;
    var y_position = 0;
    var id = 0;

    enemies_array = new Array(rows);

    for (i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        enemies_array[i] = new Array(columns);
        for (j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            x_position = j * (enemy_squadron_width / 4) + (ship_width / 2);
            y_position = i * (enemy_squadron_height / 4);

            enemies_array[i, j] = {
                x : x_position,
                y : y_position,
                width : ship_width,
                height : ship_height,
                speed : 2,
                id : id
            };

            id++;
            console.log("this one's fine: " + enemies_array[i, j].y);
        }
    }

    for (i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            console.log("This one's not fine:  " + enemies_array[i, j].y);
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is that on the first console.log, the Y attribute is being correctly printed, but on the second console.log, every Y in every element of the array is set at 0. Somehow the Y attribute is lost between the first outer for-loop and the second.

I'm surely missing something very obvious, and starting to feel a little insane.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

edit - I should mention that every other attribute is fine. Only the Y is being reset

Comment: What do you expect `enemies_array[i, j]` do? Did you mean `enemies_array[i][j]`?

Comment: Isn't that how we access multidimensional arrays? enemies_array[i][j] gives me an undefined error. Besides, all the other attributes are fine, it's just the Y that is being reset to 0. If I do enemies_array[i, j].x the values are fine, as with the rest of the attributes

Comment: No, it's not. `enemies_array[i, j]` is exactly equivalent to `enemies_array[j]` (see the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)). You'll have to change it everywhere, not only on the last line.

Comment: Thank you Juhana, that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function create_enemies(rows, columns) {

    var x_position = 0;
    var y_position = 0;
    var enemy_squadron_width = 100;
    var enemy_squadron_height = 100;
    var ship_width = 100;
    var ship_height = 100;


    var id = 0;

    var enemies_array = new Array(rows);

    for (var i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        enemies_array[i] = new Array(columns);
        for (var j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            var x_position = j * (enemy_squadron_width / 4) + (ship_width / 2);
            var y_position = i * (enemy_squadron_height / 4);
            enemies_array[i][j] = {
                x : x_position,
                y : y_position,
                width : ship_width,
                height : ship_height,
                speed : 2,
                id : id
            };

            id++;
            console.log("this one's fine: " + enemies_array[i][j].y);
        }
    }

    for (var i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            console.log("This one's not fine:  " + enemies_array[i][j].y);
        }
    }
}

create_enemies(10,10);
```

You need to acces the elements of the array by a[i][j].

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL4mwgez/1/

Comment: Thank you, Juhana already helped me earlier. I'll accept this answer nonetheless.